# Running a Windows batch file in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I trying to run my Tests cases for a project in Jenkins through DOS Command line on Windows server . I am using Jenkins ver. 1.559.

I am trying to run a Windows batch file through a Jenkins job that has the java command.

```
Under the "Build" section >> "Execute Windows Batch command" >> Command: call E:\Jenkins\App\UnitTests\App_UnitTests.bat
```

Save and Build the job.

I am getting an error and here is my Console Output

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\App Test Cases\workspace>java.exe -cp "E:\Jenkins\App\PPS\App\bin\;E:\Jenkins\App\PPS\App\lib\junit-4.10.jar;E:\Jenkins\App\PPS\App\lib\*.jar;" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.omnitracs.fra.junit.EventTests 
'java.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\App Test Cases\workspace>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . . 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\App Test Cases\workspace>EXIT
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The java command runs fine outside Jenkins.
I have set the JAVA_HOME for the local user and also the PATH variable to point to where java.exe is.

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: You need to make sure that java.exe is on the path for the user that is running the Jenkins build - or just add it to the system path.

Comment: @gareth_bowles Sorry I am a Jenkins newbie. How do I find out what user I am running as for the Jenkins job? When I run java.exe outside Jenkins - open cmd and type java it runs fine.

Comment: @Ram You configure the service to start up under a specific user account. Also, I'm guessing E: is not an actual drive and just a mapped drive. And java home is suppose to be java home. not java home\bin

Comment: @Cole9350 Under Jenkins>> Credentials >> Global Credentials I have an user configured. Is that what it is? E: is an ACTUAL drive and not mapped.

Comment: @Ram No, under winkey+r -> services.msc -> your jenkins service -> right click and properties -> logon tab -> this account -> save and restart service ... http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.com/2012/08/running-jenkins-in-windows-with-regular.html

Comment: @Cole9350 Perfect! Works now. Can you add this as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: @Ram, NP, glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a windows environment, there is some extra configuration needed for more advanced builds. Ultimately you have two options

From Jenkins, The Definitive Guide:

> This basic installation will work fine in a simple context, but you
>   will often need to fine-tune your service. For example, by default,
>   the Jenkins service will be running under the local System account.
>   However, if you are using Maven, Jenkins will need an .m2 directory
>   and a settings.xml file in the home directory. Similarly, if you
>   are using Groovy, you might need a .groovy/lib directory. And so on.
>   To allow this, and to make testing your Jenkins install easier, make
>   sure you run this service under a real user account with the correct
>   development environment set up.  Alternatively, run the application as the
>   system user, but use the System Information page in Jenkins to check
>   the /Users/johnsmart/Projects/Books/jenkins-thedefinitive- guide
>   directory, and place any files that must be placed in the user home
>   directory here....

To configure your Jenkins server to run under a service account (The suggested option), Install Jenkins as a service, and under the services properties set the log on user info.